# Android Studio 1.1.0 Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build.gradle: 1.0.+]

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

As the title indicates I cannot run an Android Project made on Android Studio 0.8 with Gradle 0.12.2 on my Android Studio 1.1.
-I have changed the classpath to: 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+' in the build.gradle file of THE PROJECT.
-I have replaced the runProGuard() with minifyEnabled true in the same file
-I replaced the previous distributionUrl
with this: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip in the gradle-wrapper.properties file

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tuwien.server_app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/sshj-0.8.1.jar')
    compile files('bcpkix-jdk15on-151.jar')
    compile files('bcprov-jdk15on-151.jar')
    compile files('slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar')
    compile files('slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar')
    compile 'com.jcraft:jzlib:1.1.1'
    compile files ('gson-1.7.1.jar')
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0"
}
```

What do I miss?? Any suggestions??

Comment: What is in your main build.gradle? The one you shared is the one that is probably under app/ module, but there is one for the whole project; share that one too. It seems that you are not including the Android Gradle plugin nor the repositories.